# Screen artifacts

Tags: laptop, gpu, visual-artifacts

Ok so my laptop screen is going crazy - photo of my screen

[image]

It happened suddenly and sometimes it goes away for a while then it comes back, I can't play games, watch videos or the screen will freeze and laptop restarts, I'm guessing its the GPU, please correct if I'm wrong and tell me what's going on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely your GPU, but it may also be a monitor problem. You can plug an external monitor and if it's showing artifacts as well - you have a GPU problem.

Sometimes you can reflow it to repair, but that is probably just a temporary fix and depending on your laptop may not be worth the money.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, I even changed my laptop screen but same thing. so it's a dying laptop right?

Comment: Yes, than you most likely have a GPU problem. You can find a local shop to try and repair it, but what they essentially do is heat up graphics chip hoping it would reconnect to the motherboard. This however fails again very quickly, especially if you have decrease in cooling performance. Note that some older laptops may have (non integrated) GPU slotted in, so it may be easier to replace, but if your computer is that old - you should really recycle it.

Comment: I read about that it might be a cooling problem but how can I try to fix that

Comment: As for the cooling you may try replacing the thermal compound, cleaning the fan and grills, but I doubt it will improve anything. GPU doesn't get that hot at startup (and yours fails at startup judging from the image), temps tend to spike when you load it with 3D application.